# Priest, inheritance, and adoption (in Catholic canon law)

Tags: canon-law, adoption, inheritance

Does the Catholic canon law say anything about the case where a Catholic priest unexpectedly inherits an estate by default since all his siblings (who don't have kids) have died?

- In the case of a priest who has taken a vow of poverty (like in a religious order): can this priest adopt an adult as "child" for inheritance purpose to dispose the assets?  If not, are there other mechanism that allow the priest to make decisions regarding the beneficiary and/or the management of the estate?
- In the case of a diocesan priest who does *not* take a vow of poverty, can he become owner of the estate and manage it?

A related question: does this inheritance now belong either to the diocese or to the religious order (like the Jesuits)?

Comment: I believe something like this happened in the case of Archbishop Vigano inheriting a large amount of money while his sibling was still alive https://www.ncregister.com/blog/archbishop-vigano-addresses-dispute-with-brother-over-family-inheritance